# google analytics not working on confirmation page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Google analytics is not returning page view for confirmation page on site. However,it's working fine on rest of pages.

Code added on confirmation page is:-

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-xxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push([
         '_addTrans',
         'xx',
         'store name',
         '10',
         '1',
         '2',
         'town',
         'state',
         'country'
    ]);
_gaq.push([
            '_addItem','xx','yy','productName', '','$18','2'
        ]);
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);
```

Is there any issue in code? Please suggest. I think maybe $ is causing issue, but I'm not able to find it written anywhere, and it needs to be checked on live site. So I want to confirm it before deploying it directly.

Thanks,

Ankit Bansal

Answer (score 1):

I would check the very first line of the code snippet you posted:

```
_gaq.push(_setAccount,UA-xxxxx-1)
```

It should look like:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-1']);
```

You can refer to the official Google Analytics documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push

Other that that, if you see any JavaScript errors appearing in your browser's developer console, it might also be worth looking into that.

Comment: Hi, My mistake, It's already in quotes but written without quotes here. Correcting it in my question. Thanks for noticing that though.

Comment: Hi! Just to be sure, do you also have square brackets (`[` and `]`) around `_setAccount` and your UA ID? And can you confirm there are no JavaScript errors on your page?

Comment: Ya, forgot to add that too in description.
Also, there is no javascript errors on page.

Comment: Your E-Commerce tracking code seems fine when looking at the [_trackTrans](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackTrans) code... Do you see the transaction in Analytics, but not the Pageview? Are you testing on *localhost*? If so, are you also setting [_setDomain](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName) to `none`?

Comment: I'm not able to get anything from confirmation page, However, it's working on rest of pages. I'm trying it on live site with domain name as site name.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not much more that I can think of without looking at a specific page online. Sorry :(